# Merge or remove repeating values in columns using Excel (or SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have a query where I join the employee table and logs table to show the logs per employee. The problem is I need to remove those duplicating column vales (show the emp details only to first row per employee). Does anyone know how to do it in Excel or SQL Server?

```
SELECT e.Employee, e.Position, e.Dept, l.Actioner, s.Status, l.ActionDate
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN logs l ON e.EmpNo = l.EmpNo
INNER JOIN Status s ON l.StatusId = s.Id
ORDER BY l.Employee, l.ActionDate
```

Original Output

```
Employee    |Position   |Dept   |Actioner   |Action     |ActionDate
emp1        |Manager    |IT     |emp1       |Submit     |01/01/2017
emp1        |Manager    |IT     |emp2       |Verify     |01/02/2017
emp1        |Manager    |IT     |emp3       |Approve    |01/03/2017
emp2        |Supervisor |HR     |emp2       |Submit     |01/12/2017
emp2        |Supervisor |HR     |emp3       |Verify     |01/13/2017
emp2        |Supervisor |HR     |emp4       |Approve    |01/14/2017
```

Desired Output

```
Employee    |Position   |Dept   |Actioner   |Action     |ActionDate
emp1        |Manager    |IT     |emp1       |Submit     |01/01/2017
                                |emp2       |Verify     |01/02/2017
                                |emp3       |Approve    |01/03/2017
emp2        |Supervisor |HR     |emp2       |Submit     |01/12/2017
                                |emp3       |Verify     |01/13/2017
                                |emp4       |Approve    |01/14/2017
```

NOTE: I prefer if this can be resolved using Excel function. Thank you!

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: if you delete those values and rearange your table, how will you know which Action belongs to which employee?

Comment: @ZoharPeled SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: What you should _really_ probably do is to normalize this table.  Remove the three employee columns and instead replace with a key into a separate table for employees.  With regards to your desired output, handle such things in the presentation layer, not the database.

Comment: @RealCheeseLord I have updated the sample for it to be clearer. As you can see, you can easily identify which Action belongs to employee because of the empty cells. This is arranged per Employee per ActionDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it in SQL Server before 2012 (when the `LAG` function was introduced).

Using a common table expression with `ROW_NUMBER`, and a `CASE` expression to return only the first `Employee`, `Position` and `Dept`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  e.Employee, 
            e.Position, 
            e.Dept, 
            l.Actioner, 
            s.Status, 
            l.ActionDate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.Employee ORDER BY l.Employee, l.ActionDate) As rn
    FROM employee e
    LEFT JOIN logs l ON e.EmpNo = l.EmpNo
    INNER JOIN Status s ON l.StatusId = s.Id
)

SELECT  CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN e.Employee END As Employee, 
        CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN e.Position END As Position, 
        CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN e.Dept END As Dept, 
        l.Actioner, 
        s.Status, 
        l.ActionDate
FROM CTE
ORDER BY l.Employee, l.ActionDate
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)